# How can I get the INET based WirelessHost speed in UDPBAsicApp message?

Tags: omnet++, inet

There is a `wirelessHost` which communicates with `standardHost` through the `AP`. `wirelessHost` is moving in `LinearMobility` with the `speed` of 40mps that is configured in `ini`.  Now I want to get the speed value in `UDPBasicApp`, and this value should be send to the reciever(`standardHost`).

Note: I'm using inet 3.6.7 and omnet++ 5.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to access directly to mobility module from the Udp app module.
Appp and mobility modules are child of host module. So, you need to write the following inside UDP module:

```
cModule* mobilityMod = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("mobility", 0);
```

Usually mobility is the name of the mobility module, if it has another name, then you have to change it in `getSubmodule()` function.
You can make a dynamic_cast to evaluate the tyoe of mobility and you will have access to its internal functions.
For example:

```
dynamic_cast<LinearMobility*>(mobilityMod)->getSpeed();
```

`getSpeed()` or any other getter or setter function.
More help in this link:
https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cModule.html

Comment: UDP module is .ned type, how can I write c++ code in .ned file. when I try to write compiler shows me error.

Comment: You need to include those fragment of code in. cc file. So, if you are using UdpBasicApp.ned then you have to include the code inside UdpBasicApp.cc, which is the class that handles all the behavior of the module.

Comment: I added this cise in UDPBasicApp.cc file's sendPacket() method but it didn't work. Please help me and tell me inwhich method I should include this packet. Thank you very much

Comment: It should work in any method. Can you share the file so I can take a deeper look??

Comment: There is no option for sending file, how can I send you, please provide me whatsapp or email? please help me.

Comment: Share it using Github or Drive

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LEMUoa7c1AS8crtVPrEILCe_6RnfMJ6Z/view?usp=sharing

thank you very much for helping me

Comment: I will take a look an will let you know

Comment: Hi, Alex do you got any point? I'm waiting in few days there is my viva.